# Why doesn't 'press-and-hold' work?

Tags: java, key, jtextarea

I have a program that uses JTextArea. When I set keyboard focus in the JTextArea in the GUI and then hold down, say, the 'E' key, only one letter 'E' appears in the area. If I want further 'E' letters, I have to release the button and press it again.

Is there a way to change this, so that, by holding the 'E' key on my keyboard, 'E' letters keep appearing until I release the key, as I am used to with most software? I'm using the OSX platform.

Example program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PressAndHold {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

    public PressAndHold() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        frame.add(textArea);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new PressAndHold();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a while loop that will append characters as long as a keyboard button is pressed.

Comment: @lmcphers That won't work. Swing is event-based and singly-threaded so you can't use a while loop to do anything between events. Attempting to do so will just lead to freezing the GUI.

Comment: This seems to work fine when I tried it. 'E' is entered multiple times while holding the key in a JTextField (OSX). Can you produce a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates the behavior you are seeing? Please also include which platform you are running on. (Windows? OSX? Linux?)

Comment: @Radiodef Ah ok.  Been a while since I've done stuff in Swing.  I thought I remember doing things like that, but apparently I'm wrong.  Thanks for your correction.

Comment: @lmcphers It may be possible to do something *similar* to what you've described using a `javax.swing.Timer` but I'm not sure it's necessary.

Comment: Just speculation, but what I'm wondering now is whether there is some other code (perhaps a FocusListener or KeyListener) which is interfering with the (normal, I think) 'key held' behavior.